# If a Linux is based off another one, does it mean compatibility with programs?

Tags: linux

A more specific example would be: if let's say I have an Ubuntu-based Linux, does it mean that programs/drivers that were made for Ubuntu will work with that Linux?

Comment: "programs/drivers" are very different things. The linux kernel offers binary compatibility for userland programs (even for those from 25 years ago), but the kernel modules ("drivers") are tied to a specific kernel version (this is the often rehashed "lack of kernel API" complaint). Instead of asking such a broad Q, better tell what your problem is exactly.

Comment: No. It's not Ubuntu, it's different than Ubuntu(although there may not be that huge difference), so a program made for Ubuntu may not work that OS.

Comment: @mosvy I asked such a broad question because I just wondered about it, I don't have any problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers usually meant in the relations to particular hardware or devices. So drivers made for Linux will generally work on any distribution (ie Debian, LinuxMint, SUSE, Red Hat, Slack etc). Now where you may have issue in this part is how the driver manufacturer distributes the driver. It wouldnt be odd to see them simply release the driver for one distribution for particular installation and then leave it up to the distribution maintainers or individuals to make their own package/do their own manual install.

As far as programs, programs that work on one Linux generally will work on a different Linux distribution so long as the necessary libraries, compilers, and other such pre-requisites are correct there as well. Although there is a similar issue as with drivers when it comes to how the program authors may only package the installation mechanism for certain distributions (Ubuntu) or even certain versions of that distribution (Ubuntu 9.10). This may be such as `super_program-ubuntu910.deb` or something. Although, they've packaged it for a Ubuntu 9.10 and you can run this of course in Ubuntu 9.10. Though, you are generally able to install and run this file on other Debian-based systems as well (such as Debian, Linux Mint). This would not be recognized by RPM-based systems though (such as Red Hat, Fedora, SUSE). To do that you would need to either build from the source code into a .rpm package. Alternatively back in the day there was a program called `alien` that could typically convert packages from `.deb` format to `.rpm` format and vice-versa. I never used it though. Not sure if it still exists.

In addendum to above, these days there are a few things that try to make the program platform agnostic. I dont have to much knowledge on these and how they work in-depthly but look into Appimage, Snap, and Flatpak but here is an article https://medium.com/nitrux/cross-distro-linux-applications-1169c3077136

I hope that helps to answer the question

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is a *distribution*, not "a Linux".

In general, all programs made for Linux can be made to run on all distributions. You may have to compile them for yourself from the source code, though.

Distributions do that work for you: They already compiled the program into some kind of binary package, and you can just install that package using the package manager that comes with your distribution.

As packages will usually depend on other packages, makeing a package from a different distribution work on a completely another distribution can be difficult.

That said, there are distributions that are closely related, use the same package manager, and often lots of identical packages (e.g. Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu). For those it can work (but won't always).

So in general, you either look if that program is already available on your distribution, or you compile it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The packages and drivers on Debian-based systems, like Ubuntu, are usually same. And Red Hat Linux-based Linuxes, like CentOS and Oracle Linux use the same packages. The [EPEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Relationship_with_Fedora) packages in both are possessed in common. But you should check before install or compile.

Comment: What is the subject in *"But should check"*? *"it"*? *"you"*? *"they"*?

Comment: Thank you for your help